# Differential of complex-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

If $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y),\, z=x+iy$, how is the differential $df$ of $f$ defined? I know that for a real-valued function $h(x,y)$, its differential $dh$ is defined as $dh=h_xdx+h_ydy$, but I am not sure what that is for $f(z)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $f=u+iv$, we have$$df=du+idv=u_xdx+u_ydy+i(v_xdx+v_ydy)=(u_x+iv_x)dx+(u_y+iv_y)dy.$$